# How to write a char buffer into a file using CLI

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I am trying to write a `char*` to a text file in Managed C++. Then I will be using this file in another unmanaged C++ application.

This is my code.

```
void DumpAllData(int buffSize, char* srs)
{
    String^ fileName = "C:\\temp\\example.bin";
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName, true, System::Text::Encoding::ASCII);

    for (int i = 0; i < buffSize; i++)
    {
        sw->Write(srs[i]);
    }
    sw->WriteLine();
    sw->Close();
}
```

I am looping through the `buffSize` for the given `char*` and writing it to a file.
The `char*` might have `'\n'` in it.
After writing the complete file, the expectation is that all data should be in a single line. But when I open the file in notepad++ the data comes up in multiple line.

I noticed that LF or CR also comes with the `char*`.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: *"the expectation is that all data should be in a single line"* + *"I noticed that LF or CR also comes with the `char*`"* => you have newlines in your input, so you'll have newlines in your output. Why did you expect to get everything on a single line in the first place? BTW your output method is inefficient, instantiate an `UnmanagedMemoryStream` from your buffer, a `FileStream` for your file, and then call `ums->CopyTo(fileStream);`

Comment: Thank you sir. This is the data I received from a socket, so I am not allowed to modify or change any stuff in the packet. Instead I should be sending the same to another application via socket communication. That is the reason I expected all data to print in one line, so that I can send back to required place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue. Instead of reading the file line by line, I read it byte by byte and used it as my wish.
Thanks for all  your time.